# Pass an argument to run function in scheduleWithFixedDelay

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

How can I pass a function in run method when calling using executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay

Eg.

```
IntStream.range(0, 4)
.forEach(
    i -> executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::runOnce, 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

So, in this how can I pass an argument to runOnce. Eg. if I wanted to send  i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what `runOnce` returns, you can change your method reference to a lambda and pass in `i` as an argument:

```
IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> { 
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> runOnce(i), 0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
});
```

Comment: Yes, its working fine. What does () -> runOnce(i) doing?

Comment: @hatellla It's a lambda, syntactic sugar for a `Runnable` whose `run` method invokes the `runOnce` method with `i` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You want `this::runOnce` to return a `Runnable` based on `i` so if you wanted a runnable to simply output `i` to the console the class would look like:

```
public class Blah {

    public void whatever() {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> {
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runOnce(i),
                0, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        });
    }

    private Runnable runOnce(int i) {
        return () -> System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I don't want to return anything, can't I just do, System.out.println(i); instead of () -> System.out.println(i);?